# list out subfolder in ftp server

Tags: c#, ftp

I just can list out the 2 main folder but I don't know now to list the another folder inside one of the main folder. So how i gonna write to list out subfolder.

```
        ftpWebRequest fq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://demo@203.106.0.0");
        fq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxxx");
        fq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)fq.GetResponse();
        Stream st = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(st);
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the path at line 
ftpWebRequest fq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://demo@203.106.0.0/xxx/xxx");